# import x from '.' is not working in a react-native(expo) project

Tags: reactjs, react-native, import, expo, eslint

I have a react-native(with expo SDK v40) project, recently, I added eslint into it, then the eslint find this problem:

```
// component-b.tsx

import ComponentA from './';
// Useless path segments for "./", should be "." eslint(import/no-useless-path-segments)

export default function() {
  return <ComponentA />;
}
```

The file structure is something like this:

```
-- index.tsx
-- component-b.tsx
```

Here is what looks like in the `index.tsx`:

```
// index.tsx

const ComponentA = () => {
  return <Text>Hello Component A.</Text>;
};

export default ComponentA;
```

I changed "./" to "." as eslint said. Then the weird thing happened:

```
Component Exception
Element type is invalid: expected a string(for built-in components) or a class/function(for composite components) but got: object. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Check the render method of `ComponentB`.
```

I got this error above.

Everything worked fine if I change "." back to "./".
I've searched on google, [expo/issues](https://github.com/expo/expo/issues), [eslint-plugin-import/issues](https://github.com/benmosher/eslint-plugin-import/issues), but I'm not lucky.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What is your TypeScript base directory path set to?

Comment: If you want to import a component from the same directory, let's say ComponentABC from the same directory, you should be importing it like so; ``import ComponentABC from './componentABC'``.

Comment: @ZAD Thanks for your reply. The TypeScript baseUrl is `./`. Yes, I should import a component like you said, but I have an `./index.tsx` here, and import it like `./` should be work(and it is working fine in a react project).